# How to create a file index in HTML

Tags: html, apache, directory

I would like to create an index like this:

http://cygwin.com/packages/x86/bind/

and I would like also to download the file when I click on its name, because if try to click on a file listed in that page you will be linked into it.

Comment: tihs line at the end might give you some hints `Apache Server at cygwin.com Port 80`

Comment: view the page source of this page.It gives an idea to design the html

Comment: @gourav so I have to manually build my HTML page? There is not a automatic procedure that list all my files?

Comment: Which language? What have you already tried?

Comment: If using Apache use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html - Will do the job for you

Comment: @FormlessCloud I said it gives you an idea. It depends on language you choose and what kind of files you are going to download and how you gonna manage the files and other stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing at cygwin.com is the default Apache's directory listing. You can configure Apache to show that when a directory is requested. Look here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings